# JavaScript function call inside another call allow you to access arguments that the "arguments[num]" can't access

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

i was learning in free code camp and i fell into a problem `arguments[1]` result into undefined when the function gets called like this `functionName(arg1) (arg2)` so for example `arguments[1]` would result in undefined but using this solved it `return (second) => addTogether(first, second);` and i don't know how a function call in the function itself could have accessed something that even the `arguments[1]` couldn't access, can anyone explain
here is the full code if anyone is interested:

```
function addTogether() {
  const [first, second] = arguments;
  if (typeof(first) !== "number")
    return undefined;
  if (second === undefined)
    return (second) => addTogether(first, second);
  if (typeof(second) !== "number")
    return undefined;
  return first + second;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call the function yourself with just one argument it returns another function.

The secret is that the value of `first` is already stored inside the closure that returns the other function from when you first called addTogether().

The returned function takes `second` as it's argument and it then calls `addTogether()` with the stored `first` from the initial call and the `second` just passed into the function calling addTogether again.

I added a console log inside addTogether to show the values of first and second for the two calls

```js
function addTogether() {
  const [first, second] = arguments;
  console.log('first = ',first, ', second = ', second)
  if (typeof(first) !== "number")
    return undefined;
  if (second === undefined)
    // `first` is already defined above from the first call
    // `second` will be passed into this new function that gets returned when you call it later
    return (second) => addTogether(first, second);
  if (typeof(second) !== "number")
    return undefined;
  return first + second;
}

// store the returned function as a variable
const fn = addTogether(5);

// now call the returned function with `second` value as parameter
console.log('Total =',fn(10))//expect 15
```

Comment: but how how does it get the value of `second` in the first place because you don't have to write `second` you can write ` return (x) => addTogether(first, x);` and it would still work how does it get the value of `second`? and even if we write `x` it would get the value of `second` how does the function know that we want the value of `second`?

Comment: In my example I call the returned function here: `fn(10)` ....  and 10 is `second`. You can see it in the console logging